# Concurrency Gem Historical Rate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, currency, currency-exchange-rates

Is it possible to get an historical exchange rate using the Concurrency Gem in Ruby on Rails? The current documentation only describe converting as at this moment: [Concurrency Gem](https://github.com/naman2202/concurrency) but it also uses data from [Currency Converter API](https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/) which has historical data available.

The current way of requesting a current exchange rate:

```
Concurrency.conversion_rate("NZD", "INR")
```

Answer (score -1):

No, the Concurrency Gem doesn't implement the APIs historical data. It only sets `q` and not `date`/`endDate` as described in the [Currency Converter API](https://www.currencyconverterapi.com/docs).

[`concurrency.rb`:](https://github.com/naman2202/concurrency/blob/master/lib/concurrency.rb#L61)

```rb
url = "https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=#{from}_#{to}&compact=ultra&apiKey=#{Concurrency.configuration.api_key}"
```

You could use [Money Historical Bank](https://github.com/atwam/money-historical-bank) instead. Here you can use a Timestamp:

```rb
require 'money/bank/historical_bank'
mh = Money::Bank::HistoricalBank.new

# Exchanges 1000 EUR to USD using Date.today (default if no date has been entered).
# Will download today's rates if none have been entered
mh.exchange_with(1000.to_money('EUR'), 'USD')

# Exchanges 1000 EUR to USD using historical rates
date = Date.new(2009,9,9)
mh.set_rate(date, 'USD', 'EUR', 0.7634)
mh.exchange_with(date, 1000.to_money('USD'), 'EUR') # => 763.4 EUR

Money.default_bank = mh
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however Money Historical Bank doesn't seem to work with historical rates - or at all. Not sure if it has something to do with having to set up API codes for the site which it pulls the data from?

I just ended up using REST-Client to pull the data from Currency Converter API, thanks for your help though.